# Deploy ASP.NET application with other components

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I've built an application with the following components:

- ASP.NET MVC 4
- SQL Server Reporting Services
- SQL Server Integration Services
- SQL Server 2012 database

Is there a platform as a service (PaaS) that will host all the code or will I have to use multiple services?

The goal for this deploy is for user testing. Eventually, the application will be migrated to an already existing .NET infrastructure so I'm looking for a transient environment.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you help me understand your question. What do you mean deploy to the web?

Comment: I mean deploy to online hosting services so others can access it (the app currently runs on my computer (localhost)). This is my first exposure to .NET so not sure how to go about doing that. For example, if I wrote a Ruby on Rails app, I could host it on Heroku. Just not sure what to do with the .NET deployment.

Comment: So, you're just asking what PaaS providers would accommodate the above?

Comment: Yep, I'll update the original question with the clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking, you *don't* want to expose your database to the web. That's just asking for trouble. You could look at AWS, or Windows Azure, GoDaddy, etc, etc for this which is usually an indicator that your question isn't a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to use something like an aws ec2 instance where you can install everything you need on a box, pay by the hour to use it, and simply terminate it when you are done.

Very cost effective for temporary servers like this.

Comment: Thanks for the aws ec2 suggestion! Getting an instance set up now :)